# About the relationship in two entities

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, bigtable

I'm thinking to create a property which store the key or the ID of the other entity as a reference to the entity.
I want to know two things. 
1. Which data should the property store, the key or the ID?
2. What should the type of the property be? maybe StringProperty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Datastore has a special property type for this: [`ReferenceProperty`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#ReferenceProperty). There are two ways to use it.

One:

```
someothermodel = db.ReferenceProperty()
```

Two:

```
someotherspecificmodel = db.ReferenceProperty(SomeModel)
```

In example 2, only models with the type of SomeModel can be assigned, in example one, any model can be assigned.

The value type of `ReferenceProperty` is `db.Key`.